# What is the value of $ x(\log x)$ when $x=0$ and $x\not \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I know that  $ x(\log x)\to 0$ when  $x \to 0$, but some people say that since $\log x$ is not defined when  $x=0$, so the value of $ x(\log x)$ can also not be found when $x=0$.

But isn't it true that if you multiply anything with 0, the answer comes out to be 0? According to me the value of $x(\log x)$ at $x=0$ should be $0$.

Comment: If you multiply something undefined by $0$ it remains undefined.

Comment: If you multiply *anything* by $0$ you get $0$. But "*nothing*" is not "*anything*".

Answer (score 4):

Using "anything" in "... multiply anything with $0$..." is an abuse of language; according to the context, that "anything" can only be a complex number. But $\log 0$ is not even defined; hence the arithmetic multiplication does not apply to $\log 0$.

If one "multiplies" an undefined thing by $0$, then he is not "playing the game".

Answer (score 4):

The function $$f(x)=x\log x$$ has a singularity at $x=0$, since $\log 0$ is undefined. However, this singularity is removable, since $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ exists. Therefore you can define a new function

$$\tilde f(x)=\begin{cases}
x\log x&x\ne 0\\
0&x=0
\end{cases}$$
This is what you looking for I guess.

btw, there is other types of [singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28mathematics%29), which are not removable.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\ln(x)$ is not defined, $x\ln(x)$ is not defined. Difficult to multiply things that do not exist.

However, since the existing definitions do not cover the case $\ln(0)$, you could **arbitrarily** choose a value for $\ln(0)$: $0$, $1$, $e$, $1664$ or your mother's birthday... There is no problem doing that, but there is no interest since the properties that works for $\ln(x)$, when $x$ is positive, would no longer be true if you include $0$ in the domain of $\ln$: the function will no longer be continuous on its whole domain and the theorem $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ is not true if one of the numbers $x$ or $y$ is equal to $0$.

The same apply to $0\ln(0)$. In that case, many people (for example, people working with entropy) defines $x\ln(x)$ as $0$ when $x=0$. They find it convenient since it makes the functions $x\ln(x)$ continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and it is all that matters for them (I am maybe exagerating here).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $x\ln x$ is undefined for $x=0$ but that doesn't matter when we ask $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x$ because we are only asking what the value is approching arbitrarily close.

However the whole "$0$ times anything equals zero" means "$0$ times any element within the ring is $0$". So does $\ln 0$ exist in reals? no it doesn't, it has no value, it is meaningless and hence it cannot be multiplied by $0$. It is like asking what is $0\cdot red$, red is not a number so how does multiplication work even then?

Answer (score 1):

The logarithmic function is not defined at $x=0$. If you draw the graph as below, you will see that $x=0$ or y-axis is an asymptote to $\log x$. 
[image]

Hence anything undefined multiplied by $0$ yields only one result: UNDEFINED.